# What is this plant with odd-pinnate leaves that's growing under my oak tree in Florida?

Tags: identification

I live in Florida, the plant is growing under my live oak tree. The plant is about one foot high.

[image]

Comment: After some discussion I think it's best I pull my answer. Lori, go ahead and put your answer in.

Comment: What happened to the discussion?  LOL, I edited my original post.  Not sure how to say its answered.

Comment: @lori Use the "Answer your question" button underneath the question. This is a Q&A site so we want questions to have matching answers, rather than asking and answering in the one post. The discussion disappeared because Escoce deleted their answer when they realized it was wrong.

Comment: @Lori the reason I pulled my answer was for safety reasons. You have the plant in front of you, I do not. I based my answers on the true leaves being alternating, whereas you said they were opposite, that's a big difference in the plant world. When I pulled my answer any comments to that answer also were pulled down.

Comment: Oh wow, didn't think of the true leaves being alternating I was just thinking of the leaflets not alternating.  I was sort of right anyhow.

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out finally Solanum seaforthianum Andrews

Its a nightshade and poisonous. Pretty berries and flowers not too good to have around my hound dog who likes eating flowers and berries.

The way I figured it out was reading some of the answers to my question.  I was rusty on leaf shapes so I looked up pinnate and palmate, found lobed pinnate and then found pinnatisect leaves. I google imaged types of plants with pinnatisect leaves and my plant showed up.